# ArcMap ArcPy - Place signs with no lat/lng on map

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, linear-referencing, trace

I'm new to ArcPy and ArcMap but I do have programming experience. What I am trying to accomplish is to take over 22,000 signs from a database and place them on a map in reference to a street layer that is there. The problem is that there is no lat/lng but the database specifies the road it is on, and the two intersections it is inbetween and the distance it is from the first intersection. I found an example of a trace tool and I am attempting to use that with little luck. I have a mainline layer of the road that I can trace and I have intersection points to reference but again, I am new to ArcMap and ArcPy so any help in the right direction would be great.

I am thinking that I will put in a loop to select the intersection that corresponds with the sign and then trace the distance from that intersection towards the other intersection point. The loop is not a problem but the trace function is rather foreign to me so I was hoping someone could provide me with a place to find some good examples or just a basic overview of how to implement a trace function. The ArcGIS site wasn't much help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is known as **[Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000001000000)** (or Dynamic Segmentation or Chainage).  You should find that much easier to use than pursuing any "trace" method.  The latter is great for editing but I consider it to be inaccessible to ArcPy.

Comment: Slightly lengthy way of doing it but I am currently using CreateRoutes_lr to create a route. Then I use LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr to the locate to the point that I need and placing a point by using MakeRouteEventLayer_lr. Then from there I am working on correctly offsetting the point. The trouble now is determining if I need to flip the line or not but Linear Referencing was definitely the way to go.